# Order of Searching by ASP .NET in ActionResult paramethers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In ActionResult we can declare parameters and ASP .NET will search for those strings in whole project.

```
 public ActionResult Index(string name, string lastname)
    {
        return Content(name+" "+lastname);
    }
```

What is the order of searching, what comes first ?

Is it searching till it finds first one that match ?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you're talking about. Could you clarify a little more?

Comment: if you write paramethers in ActionResult  ASP .NET will look for those strings in URL and somewhere else to match them. I was wonder what is the order of searching , like first is checking URL than sth .

Comment: The parameters are matched directly by their name. There is no "searching" involved: `/Home/Index?name=bill&lastname=gates`

Comment: @RaraituL so it just matching URL ?

Comment: There's no magic, part of the framework is responsible to populate those parameters from the HTTP request that comes in. Read more about the [MVC ModelBinder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)

Comment: @MTo yes, it matches the parameters from url. If the parameters from url doesn't match the parameters from ActionResult, MVC won't populate the values.